# Mysql Service in Laragon Cannot Start due to many errors

Tags: laragon

i'm using laragon 1.0.1 , i already uninstalled and reinstalled many times but its still not work.

I'm using Windows 10 , 4 Gb Ram , 64 bit

The error as follow, popup by laragon it self :

[image: Laragon Error]

Any feedback really appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder why MariaDB tried to create the file **???-pc.lower-test**
How about trying to install Laragon in other place: for example **D:\laragon**

Comment: @معاذالغفاري: It seems that you use **non-English** word in your Computer Name. I believe it is the cause of the problem.